# how to filter a column in csv by a part of string and save it in excel

Tags: python, excel, csv, filter

I have a tar files in a folder which has CSV inside it and has no headers. I need to unzip / untar these files in the folder, extract all the CSV and then filter the column number 12 with a specific string "INCM" and then save it in new excel.

I could able to extract a single tar file and filter the data in CSV. But I'm failing some where to re-iterate the same loop in untar and filter task. Due to this, I'm able to Unzip / Untar an single file in that folder, but failing to do the same for other files in that folder and append the data into the excel. Also,I'm stuck how to save the data in excel, as my inputs are from CSV.

```
import tarfile
import os
import csv

workdir = 'C:/Rajhesh/Python Exercise/OSLA/'
datadir = workdir + 'Input/'
os.chdir(datadir)
files = os.listdir(datadir)

for fname in files:
    if (fname.endswith("tar.gz")):
        tar = tarfile.open(fname, "r:gz")
        tar.extractall()
        tar.close()
    elif (fname.endswith("tar")):
        tar = tarfile.open(fname, "r:")
        tar.extractall()
        tar.close()
    column_nbr = 12
    keep = []
    with open(fname, 'r') as my_file:
        reader = csv.reader(my_file)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
            IM = row[column_nbr]
            if "INCM" in IM:
                keep.append(row)
    with open('filtered.csv', 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(keep)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for writing an Excel sheet:

```
import xlsxwriter

    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    row = 0
    column = 0

    keep = []

    for line in keep:
        line = line.split(',')  # convert each row as a list
        for cell in line: 
            worksheet.write(row, column, cell)
            column += 1  # for moving to the next cell 
        row += 1  # for moving to the next row

    workbook.close()
```

Comment: If you get any error then remove the `line = line.split(',')` line.

Comment: Thanks Ronak. Appreciate your support. But, my problem is, my code is failing to repeat the task given inside "For loop", for all tar files. I need to repeat those commands for all CSVs inside all the tar files, so that I can collect those records having "INCM" string in column no 12 (as there is no header). These collected records needs to be saved in Excel. And my input files are in CSV.

Comment: `column_nbr = 12
..........................
writer.writerows(keep)`
this part of code is not in condition so, even if your complainer don't find any tar or gz still it's processing that code so, each time it will go in that part of code so, you need to keep that code inside your condition.